# How to find YTD daily average in Power Bi?

Tags: powerbi

I am trying to figure out how to calculate a "New Measure" in my power BI visual that calculates the YTD daily average.

So for example,
my query on the backend would look like this

```
App Date   | ID  | Subject    
01\01\2022 | 123 | Math    
01\01\2022 | 456 | Science    
01\02\2022 | 789 | Science    
01\02\2022 | 012 | History    
01\03\2022 | 345 | Science    
01\03\2022 | 678 | History    
01\03\2022 | 921 | Art    
01\03\2022 | 223 | Science    
01\04\2022 | 256 | English
```

Im trying to calculate what the daily average is YTD for math, science, history etc.

I tried

1 Daily average = calculate (average(Query[app date]))

I know this is not correct but I would appreciate any help..

Answer (score 0):

Measure= AVERAGEX(VALUES(Date[APP_DATE]), [Subject])

This forumula should work to count YTD Average

Answer (score 0):

First you need to create a date table using New Table and paste this code:

```
Date = 
VAR ModelDate = 
ADDCOLUMNS(
    CALENDAR(DATE(2022,01,01), DATE(2022,12,31)),
    "Year", YEAR([Date]),
    "Month",FORMAT([Date],"mmm"),
    "MonthNumber", MONTH([Date]))
RETURN
ModelDate
```

Then Create a relationship between date table and your fact table:

[image: MarkUP]

Then Go on to write this code AS Your measure:

```
Daily Avg_YTD = 
 CALCULATE(
    AVERAGEX(
        VALUES(YourTbl[Subject]),COUNT(YourTbl[Subject])),
        DATESYTD('Date'[Date]))
```

Now If you put it on a table visual:

[image: FRRR]

I hope It solves your problem!